# Emacs - no menubar and toolbar

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I installed emacs and it worked ok. I tried to change configuration file ( I made init.el file and copied Styling (Themes & More) part from: [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/)

After this operation I lost menubar and toolbar. I deleted my init.el file but all changes are still present. How can I reset old settings. I am new with emacs and I'd like to have menubar for now. Thank you for any help.

Comment: If they exist, try also deleting (or renaming) the `.emacs` file and the `.emacs.d` directory.

Comment: I added (menu-bar-mode 1)
(tool-bar-mode 1)
(scroll-bar-mode 1) and it is ok. Although as you wrote deleting .emacs.d directory erases configuration. Thank you.

Comment: Consider familiarizing yourself with the source code at issue that you installed with the package called `better-defaults`:  http://melpa.org/packages/better-defaults-20160127.2318.el  The offending code is `(menu-bar-mode -1) (when (fboundp 'tool-bar-mode) (tool-bar-mode -1)) (when (fboundp 'scroll-bar-mode) (scroll-bar-mode -1))`  You can comment that stuff out, and then you don't need additional code to put it back to the default settings.  The whole package `better-defaults` is just a few lines, so why not just eliminate the whole package and copy what you want to your own `.emacs` file?

Comment: Note, that when modifying source code it is necessary to re-byte-compile **IF** there was a previous corresponding `*elc` file, which can be accomplished with `M-x byte-compile-file`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this function to your .emacs file to regain the missing items.

```
(defun restore-menu-bar()
  (interactive)
  (if (fboundp 'scroll-bar-mode) (scroll-bar-mode 1))
  (if (fboundp 'tool-bar-mode) (tool-bar-mode 1))
  (if (fboundp 'menu-bar-mode) (menu-bar-mode 1)))

(restore-menu-bar)
```